# silverlight slide in panel

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight-4.0

I am looking to create a custom slide in menu that will host all of my modules for my application. The part I need guidance on is how to create the animation for the panel to slide in and out.

I am looking to have a button on my application and when a user click on it I want it to expand down and right to show available modules. Is this done with the slider panel or a canvas, custom animation or something else?

Any guidance on how to do something like this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/animation-and-easing/animations-(silverlight-quickstart)

This website has an excellent tutorial about animations in silverlight for beginners, with some good code examples. Found it pretty useful when I was trying my hands with animation in silverlight.

Comment: Naked links aren't particularly useful answers. Please explain why this is solves the problem.

Comment: Gotcha, added a couple of lines to explain what the website is about

Answer (score 1):

if your using blend you will do that with a story board action, allowing you to record the key frames.
it works off of a second by second time frame, how you want it to look at the one second time frame is what you would assign it to.

Also once you have the story board action done you would assign it to the button or the object by an event such as a click or mouse over event.

Here is a link to better assist you in the matter.

[SilverLightBuzz](http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/12/animating-with-storyboards-in-blend/)